# How can I check if the symbol is on the user input?

Tags: java, arrays

I tried searching for an answer, but I don't know how to answer it. I tried making my own, but it show me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method contains(CharSequence) in the type String is not applicable for the 
arguments (char)
```

I don't know why it says charsequence when I just used a simple array. The purpose of this part of a code is like a checker for invalid inputs. Here is the code:

```
                for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
                    if(GN.contains(Integer.toString(i))){
                        checked = false;
                        if(!checked) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid type, try again.");
                            main.GivenName();
                        } else {
                            String InvalidSym = "`!@#$%^&*()_=+{}[]|\";:\\?";
                            char[] FinalCheck = new char[InvalidSym.length()];
                            for(int j = 0; j <= FinalCheck.length; j++) {
                                  FinalCheck[j] = InvalidSym.charAt(j);
                            }
                            for(int k = 0; k <= FinalCheck.length; k++) {
                                if(GN.contains(FinalCheck[k])) {
                                    checked = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } //second checker
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FinalCheck` is a char array which doesn't implemented `CharSequence` interface

so you can try

```
if(GN.contains(String.valueOf(FinalCheck[k])))
```

or you can convert `GN` into char array once and write a method to check if `FinalCheck[k]` is in GN array

Answer (score 0):

contains methods is not applicable for char value, the last for loop should contains this if statement :

```
  for(int k = 0; k <= FinalCheck.length; k++) {
     if(GN.contains(String.valueOf(FinalCheck[k]))) {
         checked = false;
      }
  }
```

on your code the FinalCheck[k] is a char value as the type of the FinalCheck array is char[]. using the valueOf will convert this char value to String value.